# Zipping folders and their contents into a .zip file in Linux

Tags: linux, zip

How do I make a .zip file that contains every file AND every folder in the directory?

Comment: I use 'tar': tar -zcvf archive.tar.gz directory/ 
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93139/can-i-zip-an-entire-folder-using-gzip

Answer (score 185):

```
zip -r foo.zip dir_path
```

Comment: The -r means recursive and tells it to go through all of the sub folders. You don't really need the `.zip` on the filename (`foo.zip`) as it will create this anyway.

Comment: @user2924019's comment that you dont need to specify the zip name is not true in CentOS7.

Comment: CentOS7 is exactly where I tested this.

Comment: Well, we've come to what is known as a Mexican standoff, now haven't we?

Comment: I'm on CentOS-7 (7.5 to be exact).  I ran `zip -r foo my_folder` and ended up with a `foo.zip`.  Hopefully this standoff can finally come to an end.

Comment: `zip -r foo.zip dir1_path dir2_path dir3_path` to archive multiple directories.

Answer (score 26):

Try:

```
zip -r filename.zip /path/to/folder
```

Note - this will go recursively, i.e. it will zip all folders and all subfolders of the given folder.

Comment: where obviously `/path/to/folder` can be a regex, like `/path/to/folder/myprefix*`, which will put in the archive only the files and folders starting by `myprefix`.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `-r` option. From [zip(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip):

> -r

Travel the directory structure recursively; for example:

```
zip -r foo foo
```

The name of the zip file comes first. "Recursively" means that the zip file will include subfolders of the given folder, the subfolders of those folders, and so on.

Comment: Where the .zip file goes after zipping?

Comment: To the path specified. `foo` in this example.

Answer (score 4):

If you are bound to a zip, I'd use:

```
zip -r zipfilename directoryPath
```

The `-r` is the key, but you can find all the options [here](http://www.perpetualpc.net/srtd_zip.html).