# Unix zip command

Tags: unix, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zipping folders and their contents into a .zip file in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/214390/zipping-folders-and-their-contents-into-a-zip-file-in-linux)

I need to zip a file on Unix machine. File is about 200MB. What is the best compression tool? and provide me the command to zip the file.

File structure:

```
- /home/testuser/myfolder/
                     |__  Myfile1.dat [200MB]
                     |__  MyFile2.dat [500MB]
```

Comment: Be aware that binary data files won't generally compress that well

Comment: Why so? Can not I achieve it anyway?

Comment: Binary files may or may not compress well depending on how much repetition they contain, but they typically contain less repetition than a text file of similar size. The exception are already-compressed file formats, such as most media formats (.jpg, .mp3, .mpg, etc.), which, well, are already compressed. You should never see more than 1-2% reduction in file size for these formats and will often see them get *bigger* when zipped (but, again, by no more than 1-2%).

Comment: well, /dev/zero contains a lot of repition :)

Comment: I'd suggest defining 'best'.  Best compression?  Best compatibility with 3rd party tools?  Best compatibility with other OSes?

Answer (score 1):

One program to zip files would be:

```
$ zip
```

To zip a directory:

```
$ zip -r archive.zip yourdirectory
```

Other popular ones are `tar` in conjuction with, e.g. Lempel-Ziv (`gzip`) or Burrows–Wheeler (`bzip`) style compression.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the "best" compression is lzma. The order of available compressions is lzma, bzip2, gzip and finally compress. Whe you are saying Unix; what do you mean? If you happen to have GNU tar and friends you best option is lzma.

lzma:

```
tar --lzma -cvf stuff.tar.lzma file1.dat file2.dat
```

bzip2:

```
tar -cvjf stuff.tar.bzip2 file1.dat file2.dat
```

gzip:

```
tar -cvzf stuff.tar.gz file1.dat file2.dat
```

Of course if you don't have GNU tools:

compress:

```
tar -cvf stuff.tar file1.dat file2.dat
compress stuff.tar
```

Comment: OP asked for 'zip'

Comment: Ok this might sound weird, but many people say zip and mean "to compress a file", thanks to WinZip. Same as when I say compress a file, I don't mean unix compress. As he was referring to the best way, I though he knew about the zip / unzip commands...

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, binary files **do not compress well** compared to plain text. I'd just gzip or bzip the file and be done with it. The time spent compressing it to the max with LZMA for example **may** eventually outweight the time for the extra few MB's of transfer, depending on your transfer medium.

eg.

```
tar czvf myfolder.tar.gz /home/testuser/myfolder
```